# FileNotFoundException during nunit3-console running

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit-console

I try to run my tests via nunit3-console. Running via Visual Studio works good. I execute this command:

`$ nunit3-console ComplexUI.dll`

but get the following input:

```
NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException : An exception occurred in the driver while loading tests.
  ----> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : ?? ??????? ????????? ???? ??? ?????? "nunit.framework, Version=3.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb" ???? ???? ?? ?? ????????????. ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.
--NUnitEngineException
An exception occurred in the driver while loading tests.
```

Symbols ???? may be in cause of my locale.

I have no idea how to resolve it

Comment: Have you moved `ComplexUI.dll` anywhere out of the `bin` directory?

Comment: Do you have a data driven test that is reading from an external file in your project? Triggering your tests in this way will run EVERY test in the DLL... is that what you expected?

Comment: Yes, i have tried to move .dll from ``bin`` directory

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, i have found alternative way to run tests. I was able to do it by running `dotnet test --no-build` in directory, where solution file `ComplexUI.sln` is placed.
It still doesn't working with `nunit3-console`. Maybe, it's some issue with current version